# Simplify an expression with the given substitution of another expression

Tags: sympy

Suppose an expression `expr2=expr3(expr1*expr2)+expr2...` How to make a simplification or substitution such that `expr1` can be replaced by a single letter `A`?

```
from sympy import Function
f= Function('f')
from sympy import *
x,y=symbols('x y',real=True)
A,B,C=symbols("A B C")

a=1/f(x)
b=(1/f(x)).diff(x)
c=(1/f(x)).diff(x,2)

func=1/f(x)*(1-f(x)**2*y)
expr=func.diff(x,2)
```

where

```
expr
(-2*y*(f(x)*Derivative(f(x), (x, 2)) + Derivative(f(x), x)**2) + 4*y*Derivative(f(x), x)**2 + (y*f(x)**2 - 1)*(Derivative(f(x), (x, 2)) - 2*Derivative(f(x), x)**2/f(x))/f(x))/f(x)
```

Clearly, `expr` contain the expression `c`

```
c
(-Derivative(f(x), (x, 2)) + 2*Derivative(f(x), x)**2/f(x))/f(x)**2
```

However, when I tried

```
expr.subs(c,C)
expr.expand().subs(c,C)
expr.simplify().subs(c,C)
expr.expand().simplify().subs(c,C)
```

None of those attempts worked.

How to simplify an expression with the given substitution of another expression?

Answer (score 1):

```py
from sympy import *
init_printing()

f= Function('f')
x,y=symbols('x y',real=True)
A,B,C=symbols("A B C")

a=1/f(x)
b=(1/f(x)).diff(x)
c=(1/f(x)).diff(x,2)

func=1/f(x)*(1-f(x)**2*y)
expr=func.diff(x,2)
expr
```

[image]

Let's look at `c`:

```py
c
```

[image]

Clearly, `expr` doesn't contain `c`, not directly. You can verify it with `expr.has(c)` which returns False. We can spot the numerator of `c` (with the sign flipped), but the denominator is applied to different expressions. That's why SymPy doesn't see `c` into `expr`: they are structurally different. But we can work on that.

```py
num, den = fraction(c)
num, den
```

[image]

Now, we look for `-num` and replace it with `C * den`:

```py
new_expr = expr.subs(-num, C * den)
new_expr
```

[image]

You can go a step further: `new_expr` is a multiplication between `1/f(x)` and an addition. Hence, we can apply the distributive property of multiplication:

```py
new_expr2 = Add(*[1 / f(x) * a for a in new_expr.args[1].args])
new_expr2
```

[image]

Here, you can verify that `new_expr2.equals(new_expr)`.